# How To Logout Using Token Stored In HttpOnly Cookie

Tags: authentication, cookies, asp.net-identity, access-token

I am currently using Microsoft's Identity to help with my Auth in an Asp .NET Web API project.  I'm generating a bearer token and storing it in a `HttpOnly` cookie named `AUTH`

Since I am not storing anything related to the token in my DB, how do I logout?  Before I stored the token in session storage so I simply removed it client side, but now since I am storing the token in a `HttpOnly` cookie I can't do anything client side.

Do I call a route on the server that responses with a new cookie `AUTH` and has a empty value?  I tried that but the response cookie from `logout` doesn't seem to replace the `HttpOnly` cookie, it just creates a session cookie.

This is how I generate the `AUTH` cookie

```
context.Response.Cookies.Append("AUTH", accessToken,
                                new Microsoft.Owin.CookieOptions
                                {
                                     HttpOnly = true,
                                     Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5)
                                });
```

This is how I generate the response from the `logout` route.

```
var authCookie = new CookieHeaderValue("AUTH", "");
var xsrfCookie = new CookieHeaderValue("XSRF", "");

ActionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage();
ActionContext.Response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { authCookie, xsrfCookie });

return ActionContext.Response;
```

For some reason, the cookie returned here doesn't override the cookie created with the auth token.

Is this the best strategy to logout a user while storing an auth token in a `HttpOnly` cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not storing the auth token then you cannot invalid it.  So you can force the browser to remove the Cookie from the server.  Try adding the `Domain` and `Path`.  You can also set the `Expires` to yesterday so the browser removes the cookie as soon as it receives it.

```
authCookie.HttpOnly = true;
authCookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1);
authCookie.Domain = "localhost";
authCookie.Path = "/";

xsrfCookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1);
xsrfCookie.Domain = "localhost";
xsrfCookie.Path = "/";
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution seems to be storing an additional (non-HTTPOnly) cookie which has a "signature" that can validate if the original HttpOnly cookie is still valid.

On backend, you should check that HttpOnly cookie is valid and also check the value (signature) of the non-HttpOnly cookie, so you know if client-side has invalidate it. There are many techniques to do this. Just make sure you can't get the content of HttpOnly cookie using the non-HttpOnly one.

Another solution would be to add a new cookie/local storage when the user logs out like "has_logout" and then, on the next successful request, if "has_logout" is true you should call /logout endpoint.

Hope that makes sense